# Tracking email delivery using API

Tags: marketing-cloud, history-tracking

Once we send email using REST API https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/0df05557-9253-41c3-bdc0-29d90612fa31/send?access_token=.....;
a. do we get token id?
b. how do we verify delivery status using API

Please guide.

Thanks,
Ganga

Answer (score 1):

You will not receive a token id, but you will receive a successful 202 response like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
```

For more info, check out this page - https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/messaging/messageDefinitionSends.html